# How to sort data from a custom pagination in CAKEPHP2.x?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I get the today data:

```
public function index() {
    $this->Apertura->recursive = 0;
    $now = new DateTime();
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Apertura.created >= ' => $now->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00')));  
    $this->set('aperturas',
        $this->Apertura->find('all', $options),
        $this->Paginator->paginate('Apertura', array('Apertura.created >= ' => $now->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'))));
}
```

But when I clic a header column I can't sort the table:

```
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id',"ID"); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Vendedore.nombre',"Vendedor"); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('vehiculo_id',"Vehículo"); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('observaciones',"Observaciones"); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('created',"Hora y fecha"); ?></th>
```

If I remove the **Condition** and the custom **Paginate** I can sort the table. What is happening?

Comment: And the error is...? `I can't sort the table` is a pretty poor description of the problem. Please read http://university.utest.com/writing-quality-bug-reports-and-utest-etiquette/

Comment: Eeey man, there are no error notification in CakePHP2.x, I executed the query that was autogenerated by debug kit of Cake in mysql and all is perfect, I think that the error is in the custom paginate but I don't know why. Sorry for my English. n.n

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the solution was:

```
public function index() {
    $this->Apertura->recursive = 0;
    $now = new DateTime();
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'conditions' => array('Apertura.created >= ' => $now->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00')),
        'limit' => 10
    );

    $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Apertura');

    $this->set('aperturas',$data);
}
```